# Use PICkitS.dll with Qt project

Tags: c#, c++, qt, dll

I'm new to programming with Qt but I am sure that you have an answer to my question.
I'm trying to develop a GUI that interfaces with the PICkit Serial Analyzer (see this link http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DV164122). I want to use the PICKitS.dll to communicate with the above "Analyzer" but I have difficulties in integrating the dll with my project. They do not supply any .h or .tbl files but they give a function prototype list (see http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PICkitS%20Function%20Prototypes%20v2-4.pdf). Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First page, description:

> This document describes the functions available in PICkitS.dll. These functions can be called from any .NET application. While it may
>   be possible to use PICkitS.dll in a non .NET environment, non .NET applications are not supported at this time.

**So, it was written in .NET/C# ABI, not C++.**

That is not a header file based language, but more like module and that is a lot more convenient than the creepy header file thing in C++ inherited from C. Either way, I do not suggest to use this directly in a Qt project. You would need something like C++/CLI, etc.

Comment: Yes, it can be easily used from C++ by writing a C++/CLI shim.